# firefox: one form multiple password fields

Tags: firefox, passwords, forms

If there is a form with more than one password field, Firefox 3.5 will remember only one password.

[image: Screenshot]

How do I make Firefox to remember two passwords for a form with a single login?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an Addon like [Sxipper](http://www.sxipper.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is it can't without adding something. You can set up multiple username / password pairs per website, but you can only have one password per pair. The above mentioned addon Sxipper may fix this.