# Firefox saving password for a 3-field password form in Firefox

Tags: firefox, passwords, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [firefox: one form multiple password fields](https://superuser.com/questions/98593/firefox-one-form-multiple-password-fields)

I've been requested to find a method of saving passwords on a form that uses three inputs, all set as type="password".  It seems that Firefox will only save the password for the first password input.  Here's the code foundation, which I simplified.

```
<FORM NAME = "PSWRD" ACTION="index.pgm" Method="POST" TARGET="frame">
<INPUT TYPE="PASSWORD" NAME="PASSWORD1" SIZE="5" MAXLENGTH="5">
<INPUT TYPE="PASSWORD" NAME="PASSWORD2" SIZE="10" MAXLENGTH="10">
<INPUT TYPE="PASSWORD" NAME="PASSWORD3" SIZE="10" MAXLENGTH="10">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="ENTER">
</form>
```

If possible, how do I get firefox to retain the password for all three input fields so I'm able to login without typing the last two?

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: @chris: are you looking for a firefox addon or configuration tweak (supposing one exists)?   or is this something that needs to be done in the HTML or otherwise on the server?

Comment: Duplicate? http://superuser.com/questions/98593/firefox-one-form-multiple-password-fields

Comment: Edited to clarify question, which is, How to set firefox to remember all three password input fields".  I've never come across any other login type like this.  Perhaps it's an attempt by the site owner to completely prevent saved passwords.

Comment: @HelloWorld, that looks like a definite duplicate, thanks

Comment: @helloworld: good find.  @chris: then can we close this one so answers get funnelled to the other one?